# Map returns last data only in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-8

I'm a fresher to spring and java 8. I grouped a list using lambda expression and got this format.

```
{
    "2016": [
                {"title":"Management","avg":0},
                {"title":"Satisfaction","avg":0}
            ],
    "2017": [
                {"title":"aaa","avg":19},
                {"title":"Energy","avg":6},
                {"title":"energy","avg":17}
            ],
    "2019": [
                {"title":"Satisfaction","avg":0}
            ]
}
```

I need to get all data like this format

```
{"year":2016,"Management":0,"Satisfaction":0},
{"year":2017,"Stress":19,"Energy":6,"Workload":17},
{"year":2019,"Satisfaction":0}
```

So I wrote a java code,

```
Map<String, Integer> mapNew = null;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Tyma>> ee : mapList.entrySet()) {  //looping the output of lambda expression
        mapNew = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        mapNew.put("year",ee.getKey());
        List<Tyma> li = ee.getValue();

        for (Tyma dept : li) {
            mapNew.put(dept.getTitle(), dept.getAvg());    //getters of Tyma class
        }

    }
```

When i return `mapNew` outside of the loop, it returns last data only(`{"year":2019,"Satisfaction":0}`) . But I need to get all data.

I thought, when we put `mapNew = new HashMap<String, Integer>();` inside the parent loop, it will create new objects in each iteration.

I tried my best using ebooks and references. Feel its helpful if anyone solves it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: search for *json objectmapper*

Comment: Not sure about from where you get the data. But your new json structure could be a simple java pojo representation.

Comment: You can't have duplicated keys in map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are creating multiple `Map`s and trying to store them in the same variable, so of course only the last `Map` will be referenced by the variable in the end.

You should store them in some `Collection`.

For example, you can store them in a `List`:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> maps = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Tyma>> ee : mapList.entrySet()) {  //looping the output of lambda expression
    Map<String, Integer> mapNew = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    maps.add(mapNew);
    mapNew.put("year",ee.getKey());
    List<Tyma> li = ee.getValue();

    for (Tyma dept : li) {
        mapNew.put(dept.getTitle(), dept.getAvg());    //getters of Tyma class
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i got what was my fault.

Answer (score 0):

When you write this line in for,

**mapNew = new HashMap();**

each time when loop run it creates new object of hash map.so at last it have only one data in list.

and you get only last record.